# vim: Change the behavior of visual block mode to force highlighting of columns

Tags: vim

I am new to vim and this was difficult for me to google because I am not sure how to articulate what I want to do.

Using this screenshot as a reference:
[image]

I want to highlight the following block of text:
[image]

Is there a way to force vim to highlight an arbitrary block of text like this?

I can highlight text in the square from line 8 to line 11, but when I move down to the closing bracket it just highlights a single column.

From here:
[image]

If I move down one row it only selects the text in the first screenshot.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to select the whitespace in front of each line? Also, what is the purpose of selecting the text? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-- VISUAL BLOCK --` mode (by default you enter this mode with <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>).  Start on the column you want to start on.  Enter the mode and move to end of the longest line (with <kbd>$</kbd> if you wish).  This will highlight the entire line for other blocks as you continue to move up.

Comment: But how do I highlight that square of text I have in the screenshot? I can highlight text in the square from line 8 to line 11, but when I move down to the closing bracket it just highlights a single column.

Comment: whoops never mind, I was using visual block mode and should have just been using visual mode.